# Inverse $z$-transform of a transfer function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter-design, z-transform

I have designed a Butterworth highpass filter (HPF) of 4th order with cutoff frequency high enough to give a gain of $3$ at high frequencies. I want to find the inverse $z$-transform using MATLAB.

```
L=4;
OSR = 16;
[b,a] = butter(L,0.259,'high');
b = b/b(1);
fvtool(b,a);
H = tf(b,a,[],'variable','z^-1');
```

`iztrans` doesn't seem to support `tf` or `zpk`.

Comment: Can you please rephrase this question because the way it is put at the moment is more about doing things in MATLAB and less about DSP. In the meantime, if you were aware of the z-transform's poles and zero locations, how would you go about finding the inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `iztrans` only supports symbolic expressions. This should do the trick:

`[num,den] = tfdata(H);
syms z
H_sym = poly2sym(cell2mat(num),z)/poly2sym(cell2mat(den),z);
h_inv = iztrans(H_sym);`

Comment: the code seems ok , but then can u tell me what actually is being done here and when i open h_inv in workspace , i don't see any data in it,why?

Comment: First, you store in two different variables (`num` and `den`) the coefficientes of the numerator and the denominator, respectively, of your transfer function. Then, using the function `poly2sym` you use those coefficientes to create a __symbolic__ polynomial with the previously declared symbolic variable `z`. So now you are all set to pass this function to `iztrans`, which only accepts symbolic expressions as inputs. Don't use the Workspace to see `h_inv`, just write `h_inv` and press Enter in the commandline and you'll see the result (or use MuPAD for a more friendly visualization).